# How do I fix this "Ghost" Bug?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I know how to print out embeds normally, but this time it's confusing. I even went into the effort of creating each and every separate embed in a different if statement.

Code:

```
 
@client.command()
async def quizintsci(ctx,*, unit):
  unit = int(unit)
  if unit == 1:
    answer = ""
    wrongAnswer1 = ""
    wrongAnswer2 = ""
    obvWrongAnswer = ""
    questions1=["Which of these observations are qualitative observations?","I","FairOPShotgun","FairOPBot","She","He","No_lucas"]
    answerToExpect = ""
    questionNum = random.randint(0,len(questions1)-1)
    questionToAsk = questions1[questionNum]
    if questionNum == 0:

      correctAnswer = ["Luster", "Color", "Brightness", "Smoothness"]
      wrongAnswer = ["Time", "Price", "Height", "Weight", "Volume", "Density", "Percentage", "Ratio", "Money", "Statistics", "John weighs 90 pounds", "The volume of a sphere is 200cm^3", "There are 100 people living in this town", "Each class has 16 students", "Age", "Temperature"]
      obviouslyWrongAnswers = ["Dog", "X+Y=13", "I have a pencil case", "The camera took a picture", "I love english class", "Popcorn", "Microphone"]
      answer = correctAnswer[random.randint(0, len(correctAnswer) -1)]
      wrongAnswer1 = wrongAnswer[random.randint(0, len(wrongAnswer) -1)]
      wrongAnswer2 = wrongAnswer[random.randint(0, len(wrongAnswer) -1)]
      obvWrongAnswer = obviouslyWrongAnswers[random.randint(0, len(obviouslyWrongAnswers) -1)]
    randomNum = random.randint(0, 3)
    if randomNum == 0:
      embedQuiz = discord.Embed(title="", description="", color=0xFFFFFF)
      embedQuiz.set_author(name="Science Question", url= "https://youtube.com/fairopshotgun",icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/859474000145154098.png?v=1")
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = questionToAsk, value = "** **", inline = True)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "A: ", value = answer, inline = False)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "B: ", value = wrongAnswer1, inline = True)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "C: ", value = wrongAnswer2, inline = False)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "D: ", value = obvWrongAnswer, inline = True)
      embedQuiz.set_footer(text='https://youtube.com/fairopshotgun',icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/861325953191116813/895753939276931082/download.jpeg")
      await ctx.reply(embed = embedQuiz, mention_author = False)
      answerToExpect = "A"
    elif randomNum == 1:
      embedQuiz = discord.Embed(title="", description="", color=0xFFFFFF)
      embedQuiz.set_author(name="Science Question", url= "https://youtube.com/fairopshotgun",icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/859474000145154098.png?v=1")
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = questionToAsk, value = "** **", inline = True)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "A: ", value = wrongAnswer1, inline = False)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "B: ", value = answer, inline = True)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "C: ", value = wrongAnswer2, inline = False)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "D: ", value = obvWrongAnswer, inline = True)
      embedQuiz.set_footer(text='https://youtube.com/fairopshotgun',icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/861325953191116813/895753939276931082/download.jpeg")
      await ctx.reply(embed = embedQuiz, mention_author = False)
      answerToExpect = "B"
    elif randomNum == 2:
      embedQuiz = discord.Embed(title="", description="", color=0xFFFFFF)
      embedQuiz.set_author(name="Science Question", url= "https://youtube.com/fairopshotgun",icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/859474000145154098.png?v=1")
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = questionToAsk, value = "** **", inline = True)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "A: ", value = wrongAnswer1, inline = False)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "B: ", value = wrongAnswer2, inline = True)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "C: ", value = answer, inline = False)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "D: ", value = obvWrongAnswer, inline = True)
      embedQuiz.set_footer(text='https://youtube.com/fairopshotgun',icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/861325953191116813/895753939276931082/download.jpeg")
      await ctx.reply(embed = embedQuiz, mention_author = False)
      answerToExpect = "C"
    elif randomNum == 3:
      embedQuiz = discord.Embed(title="", description="", color=0xFFFFFF)
      embedQuiz.set_author(name="Science Question", url= "https://youtube.com/fairopshotgun",icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/859474000145154098.png?v=1")
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = questionToAsk, value = "** **", inline = True)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "A: ", value = wrongAnswer1, inline = False)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "B: ", value = wrongAnswer2, inline = True)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "C: ", value = obvWrongAnswer, inline = False)
      embedQuiz.add_field(name = "D: ", value = answer, inline = True)
      embedQuiz.set_footer(text='https://youtube.com/fairopshotgun',icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/861325953191116813/895753939276931082/download.jpeg")
      await ctx.reply(embed = embedQuiz, mention_author = False)
      answerToExpect = "D"
    userInput = await client.wait_for("message")
    if str(userInput.content) == answerToExpect:
      await ctx.send("NO WAY! You got the question correct, " + ctx.message.author.display_name + "!")
      
    else:
      await ctx.send("RIP!! "+ ctx.message.author.display_name+ ", you got the question wrong! The correct answer was *" + str(answer) + "*.")
```

When I use the command, It doesn't show anything. And I get an error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 152, in quizintsci
    await ctx.reply(embed = embedQuiz, mention_author = False)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/context.py", line 340, in reply
    return await self.message.reply(content, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/message.py", line 1358, in reply
    return await self.channel.send(content, reference=self, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1065, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.1.value: This field is required
In embed.fields.2.value: This field is required
In embed.fields.3.value: This field is required
In embed.fields.4.value: This field is required

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.1.value: This field is required
In embed.fields.2.value: This field is required
In embed.fields.3.value: This field is required
In embed.fields.4.value: This field is required
```

Why is this? I obviously have the value set for every single embed, so I don't know why it is saying that the field is required.

Comment: We can not trace through code that takes random routes. Create a minimal working and deterministic example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers only get defined when the variable `questionNum` is 0. So the embed fields are all empty when the questionNum is not 0.

I'm not really certain what your end result should look like but you can either indent everything by 1 starting at the `randomNum = random.randint(0, 3)` line to only use these answers when the `questionNum` is 0, or you can take the random logic defining the answers out of your `if questionNum == 0:` block. Either one should work.

Comment: I didn't realize that the entire bottom part was not indented. Thanks!!!